# Formatação para dispositivos moveis

Tags: html5, css3

Eu posso usar `@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {}` para que meu código funcione apenas em dispositivos moveis ?

Pois creio que celulares e *smartphones* são os únicos que possuem `$(window).height()` maior que `$(window).width()` ou a altura da tela maior que a largura.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor explicar o que pretende fazer.

Comment: É possível o height ser maior do que width em desktops, muitos designers usam o monitor virado lateralmente para aumentar a área visual vertical para desenhar. Logo isso não pode ser um fator determinante para você verificar se é ou não mobile. Veja a resposta do @Lucas abaixo, com css é o melhor jeito

Answer (score 1):

Não, porque *smartphones* e *tablets* ficam em *landscape* quando girados. Por isso é bom especificar também os limites em "px".

[Neste link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) tem *media queries* padrões para os dispositivos. Mas cada *layout* é um *layout*, portanto se baseia nesse padrão mas testa os *breakpoints* da página e edita as *media queries* como for preciso.

Podes fazer manualmente, diminuindo o tamanho da janela do navegador, usando extensões (eu uso [essa](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/viewport-resizer/kapnjjcfcncngkadhpmijlkblpibdcgm) no Chrome) ou *sites* como [esse](https://www.responsinator.com).